# PHP website file transfer

Tags: php, ftp, streaming, file-transfer

I want to build a website with PHP where my users can host their music files on my server. When my users log into my site, they are presented with a file directory of all their songs, and can drag and drop to add new ones to their collection, delete old ones hosted on my server, rename them, stream music, download it, etc, etc.

My question is this: what is the best way to facilitate this file transfer/showing directories/all stuff mentioned above? FTP? HTTP requests? Speed is key for me. Suggestions?

(And if you might be able to point me to a framework to start with in your response that would be really cool too)

Comment: If you want this to work in a browser, HTTP is pretty much your only choice. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously, streaming musics will require HTTP connection. While you said Speed is key for you, you will need to have a good hosting service which will allow you to allow high traffic (music transfer) as well as good bandwidth.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear - obviously a site uses HTTP. but should I use PHP to initiate an FTP transfer to download music? Or should I have my server make a HTTP POST with the file in it?

Comment: no. just direct user to mp3 file (example

Comment: Streaming, for example Shoutcast, is just http. Try it with a plain MP3 file on your site and try to access it with Winamp or Windows Media Player, and see if it behaves as you want. You can also use an m3u wrapper (which is just a text file containing URLs of mp3 files). You could use a Flash widget to play music, which in turn needs an URL of an mp3 file to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript, jQuery, php's [opendir();](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), php's [readdir();](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) with combination of ajax

for streaming, flash player